# Unable to get advertising id

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-things

While running the demo (https://github.com/androidthings/doorbell) on my respberry PI, I run into error like the following:

```
01-01 00:11:00.830 5672-5672/com.company.androidthings.doorbell I/CameraManagerGlobal: Connecting to camera service
01-01 00:11:00.835 5672-5672/com.company.androidthings.doorbell D/DoorbellCamera: Using camera id 0
01-01 00:11:00.853 5672-5723/com.company.androidthings.doorbell D/DoorbellCamera: Opened camera.
01-01 00:11:00.995 5672-5715/com.company.androidthings.doorbell I/FA: This instance being marked as an uploader
01-01 00:11:01.122 5672-5715/com.company.androidthings.doorbell D/FA: Unable to get advertising id: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException: com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzt.zzlx(Unknown Source)
01-01 00:11:01.253 5672-5732/com.company.androidthings.doorbell D/FirebaseInstanceId: background sync failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE, retry in 10s
```

The following is the method I tried:

1. I did some research and find the following relevant post:
   adjust/unity_sdk#88

Following the instruction to install play service with android SDK manage tool (using android studio). Clear the project. Rebuild. Install the new apk into respberry PI but still have the same error log.

I also checked on the firebase console, no picture was updated. Even from the android monitor, it was confirmed that button was pushed camera works as expected.

2. Regarding internet connection, I installed another app on the raspberry PI. It successfully sent the info to the server. It confirms the connectivity works as expected.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Internet was connected. Raspberry PI is configured to connect with wifi router

Answer (score 1):

The log message you are seeing is from FirebaseAnalytics (the "FA" in the log tag), and makes sense since analytics is not enabled in this sample (unless you added code to enable it). Notice this is also a debug message (the "D" in the log tag) and not an error/warning.

This should not be affecting the Doorbell sample, so if you are not able to get the images uploaded properly to Firebase there is likely something else wrong with the project configuration and perhaps there are other clues deeper in the log.

Comment: Thanks! your comment helps me get ride of the distraction of "Unable to get advertising id:". It turns out that configuration is not appropriate. It uses the new SDK path which doesn't install google play service. Once I switch to the default SDK path of system which installed google play service. The logs looks different event though that message "Unable to get advertising id:" is still there. It seems (from FA log) the app can talk to the server. I'm still working on other issues.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that configuration is not appropriate. It uses the new SDK path which doesn't install google play service. Once I switch to the default SDK path of system which installed google play service. The logs looks different event though that message "Unable to get advertising id:" is still there. It seems (from FA log) the app can talk to the server.

```
04-24 15:22:53.659 16642-16642/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
04-24 15:22:53.661 16642-16642/? W/art: Unknown instruction set features for ARM CPU variant (generic) using conservative defaults
04-24 15:22:53.709 16642-16649/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
04-24 15:22:53.709 16642-16649/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
04-24 15:22:54.610 16642-16642/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.company.androidthings.doorbell-1/lib/arm
04-24 15:22:54.678 16642-16642/com.company.androidthings.doorbell D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is not linked. Skipping initialization.
04-24 15:22:54.712 16642-16642/com.company.androidthings.doorbell W/InstanceID/Rpc: Found 10007
04-24 15:22:54.723 16642-16642/com.company.androidthings.doorbell D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
04-24 15:22:54.812 16642-16642/com.company.androidthings.doorbell I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 9452
04-24 15:22:54.812 16642-16642/com.company.androidthings.doorbell I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
04-24 15:22:54.812 16642-16642/com.company.androidthings.doorbell D/FA: Debug logging enabled
04-24 15:22:54.812 16642-16642/com.company.androidthings.doorbell D/FA: AppMeasurement singleton hash: 202124672
04-24 15:22:54.906 16642-16642/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: Collection enabled
04-24 15:22:54.907 16642-16642/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: App package, google app id: com.company.androidthings.doorbell, 1:821276198771:android:044f9c86291658f3
04-24 15:22:54.980 16642-16642/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: Registered activity lifecycle callback
04-24 15:22:54.986 16642-16642/com.company.androidthings.doorbell I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
04-24 15:22:54.989 16642-16642/com.company.androidthings.doorbell I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
04-24 15:22:55.000 16642-16666/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: State of service unknown
04-24 15:22:55.000 16642-16666/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: Checking service availability
04-24 15:22:55.015 16642-16666/com.company.androidthings.doorbell W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play Store is missing.
04-24 15:22:55.015 16642-16666/com.company.androidthings.doorbell W/FA: Service invalid
04-24 15:22:55.016 16642-16666/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: Setting useService: false
04-24 15:22:55.019 16642-16666/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: Using local app measurement service
04-24 15:22:55.449 16642-16642/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: onActivityCreated
04-24 15:22:55.449 16642-16642/com.company.androidthings.doorbell D/DoorbellActivity: Doorbell Activity created.
04-24 15:22:55.450 16642-16642/com.company.androidthings.doorbell D/DoorbellActivity: No permission
04-24 15:22:55.502 16642-16666/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 331914987
04-24 15:22:55.530 16642-16642/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: Local AppMeasurementService is starting up
04-24 15:22:55.563 16642-16642/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: Bound to IMeasurementService interface
04-24 15:22:55.565 16642-16666/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: Connected to service
04-24 15:22:55.566 16642-16666/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 1
04-24 15:22:59.196 16642-16666/com.company.androidthings.doorbell W/art: Long monitor contention with owner pool-2-thread-1 (16678) at long com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.RSA_generate_key_ex(int, byte[])(NativeCrypto.java:-2) waiters=0 in java.lang.String com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.get(java.lang.String, java.lang.String) for 3.621s
04-24 15:22:59.236 16642-16666/com.company.androidthings.doorbell I/FA: This instance being marked as an uploader
04-24 15:22:59.696 16642-16666/com.company.androidthings.doorbell D/FA: Unable to get advertising id: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException: com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzt.zzlx(Unknown Source)
04-24 15:22:59.711 16642-16666/com.company.androidthings.doorbell D/FA: Setting user property: _fot, 1493049600000
04-24 15:22:59.719 16642-16666/com.company.androidthings.doorbell D/FA: User property set: _fot, 1493049600000
04-24 15:22:59.723 16642-16666/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: Logging event: origin=auto,name=_f,params=Bundle[{_c=1}]
04-24 15:22:59.790 16642-16666/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: Saving event, name, data size: _f, 22
04-24 15:22:59.792 16642-16666/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: Event recorded: Event{appId='com.company.androidthings.doorbell', name='_f', params=Bundle[{_c=1, _o=auto}]}
04-24 15:22:59.802 16642-16666/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: Upload scheduled in approximately ms: 14436
04-24 15:22:59.807 16642-16666/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: Background event processing time, ms: 84
04-24 15:22:59.808 16642-16666/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: Logging event: origin=auto,name=_e,params=Bundle[{_et=1}]
04-24 15:22:59.840 16642-16666/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: Saving event, name, data size: _e, 23
04-24 15:22:59.841 16642-16666/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: Event recorded: Event{appId='com.company.androidthings.doorbell', name='_e', params=Bundle[{_o=auto, _et=1}]}
04-24 15:22:59.847 16642-16666/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: Upload scheduled in approximately ms: 14390
04-24 15:22:59.853 16642-16666/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: Background event processing time, ms: 45
04-24 15:23:04.241 16642-16666/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from AppMeasurementService
04-24 15:23:04.276 16642-16642/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: onUnbind called for intent. action: com.google.android.gms.measurement.START
04-24 15:23:04.277 16642-16642/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: Local AppMeasurementService is shutting down
04-24 15:23:05.504 16642-16666/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: Session started, time: 331924989
04-24 15:23:05.550 16642-16666/com.company.androidthings.doorbell I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
04-24 15:23:05.552 16642-16666/com.company.androidthings.doorbell D/FA: Logging event (FE): _s, Bundle[{_o=auto}]
04-24 15:23:05.555 16642-16666/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: Using local app measurement service
04-24 15:23:05.562 16642-16642/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: Local AppMeasurementService is starting up
04-24 15:23:05.564 16642-16642/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: Bound to IMeasurementService interface
04-24 15:23:05.564 16642-16666/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: Connected to service
04-24 15:23:05.565 16642-16666/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 1
04-24 15:23:05.572 16642-16666/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: Logging event: origin=auto,name=_s,params=Bundle[{_o=auto}]
04-24 15:23:05.594 16642-16666/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: Saving event, name, data size: _s, 14
04-24 15:23:05.596 16642-16666/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: Event recorded: Event{appId='com.company.androidthings.doorbell', name='_s', params=Bundle[{_o=auto}]}
04-24 15:23:05.655 16642-16666/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: Upload scheduled in approximately ms: 14850
04-24 15:23:05.660 16642-16666/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: Background event processing time, ms: 89
04-24 15:23:10.577 16642-16666/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from AppMeasurementService
04-24 15:23:10.616 16642-16642/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: onUnbind called for intent. action: com.google.android.gms.measurement.START
04-24 15:23:10.618 16642-16642/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: Local AppMeasurementService is shutting down
04-24 15:23:20.547 16642-16642/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: Local AppMeasurementReceiver got: com.google.android.gms.measurement.UPLOAD
04-24 15:23:20.562 16642-16642/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: Local AppMeasurementService is starting up
04-24 15:23:20.564 16642-16642/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: Local AppMeasurementService called. startId, action: 1, com.google.android.gms.measurement.UPLOAD
04-24 15:23:20.588 16642-16666/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: Fetching remote configuration: com.company.androidthings.doorbell
04-24 15:23:20.598 16642-16642/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: Local AppMeasurementService processed last upload request
04-24 15:23:20.598 16642-16642/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: Local AppMeasurementService is shutting down
04-24 15:23:20.601 16642-17004/com.company.androidthings.doorbell D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
04-24 15:23:21.835 16642-16666/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: Parsed config. version, gmp_app_id: 1492543680583000, 1:821276198771:android:044f9c86291658f3
04-24 15:23:21.841 16642-16666/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: Successfully fetched config. Got network response. code, size: 200, 52
04-24 15:23:21.892 16642-16666/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: event, affected audience count: _f, 0
04-24 15:23:21.896 16642-16666/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: event, affected audience count: _e, 0
04-24 15:23:21.899 16642-16666/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: event, affected audience count: _s, 0
04-24 15:23:21.901 16642-16666/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: property, affected audience count: _fot, 0
04-24 15:23:21.924 16642-16666/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: Saving bundle, size: 301
04-24 15:23:21.947 16642-16666/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: Uploading data. app, uncompressed size, data: com.company.androidthings.doorbell, 356, 
                                                                       batch {
                                                                         bundle {
                                                                           protocol_version: 1
                                                                           platform: android
                                                                           gmp_version: 9452
                                                                           uploading_gmp_version: 9452
                                                                           gmp_app_id: 1:821276198771:android:044f9c86291658f3
                                                                           app_id: com.company.androidthings.doorbell
                                                                           app_version: 1.0
                                                                           app_version_major: 1
                                                                           firebase_instance_id: eNnLI0cB484
                                                                           dev_cert_hash: -8029454304837808102
                                                                           app_store: manual_install
                                                                           upload_timestamp_millis: 1493047401878
                                                                           start_timestamp_millis: 1493047379237
                                                                           end_timestamp_millis: 1493047385505
                                                                           app_instance_id: 570e158a1616db1ea428bad0ac67c079
                                                                           os_version: 7.0
                                                                           device_model: iot_rpi3
                                                                           user_default_language: en-us
                                                                           time_zone_offset_minutes: 0
                                                                           bundle_sequential_index: 1
                                                                           service_upload: false
                                                                           user_property {
                                                                             set_timestamp_millis: 1493047379237
                                                                             name: _fot
                                                                             int_value: 1493049600000
                                                                           }
                                                                           event {
                                                                             name: _f
                                                                             timestamp_millis: 1493047379237
                                                                             previous_timestamp_millis: 0
                                                                             param {
                                                                               name: _c
                                                                               int_value: 1
                                                                             }
                                                                             param {
                                                                               name: _o
                                                                               string_value: auto
                                                                             }
                                                                           }
                                                                           event {
                                                                             name: _e
                                                                             timestamp_millis: 1493047379237
                                                                             previous_timestamp_millis: 0
                                                                             param {
                                                                               name: _o
                                                                               string_value: auto
                                                                             }
                                                                             param {
                                                                               name: _et
                                                                               int_value: 1
                                                                             }
                                                                           }
                                                                           event {
                                                                             name: _s
                                                                             timestamp_millis: 1493047385505
                                                                             previous_timestamp_millis: 0
                                                                             param {
                                                                               name: _o
                                                                               string_value: auto
                                                                             }
                                                                           }
                                                                         }
                                                                       }
04-24 15:23:21.950 16642-17004/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: Uploading data. size: 315
04-24 15:23:22.025 16642-16666/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: Upload scheduled in approximately ms: 3599959
04-24 15:23:22.030 16642-16666/com.company.androidthings.doorbell V/FA: Successful upload. Got network response. code, size: 204, 0
```